# Compare a string row

Tags: c#

Let´s say that I have a string that looks like this:

```
string WidthStr= "0086;0086;0086;0086;0086;0086;0086;0086;0085;";
```

And then i´m picking up the first number:

```
FirstRollWidthStr = WidthPadLeft.Substring(0, 4);
```

The question I have is: Is it possible to compare the data i that i got from the row below (`FirstRollWidthStr = WidthPadLeft.Substring(0, 4);`) with the rest?

So from FirstRollWidthStr = WidthPadLeft.Substring(0, 4); i got: 0086. And there are more numbers in string WidthStr, and the last number are 0085 so it´s different from 0086 so i want to pick up the numbers who are different from the first number.

Comment: How about: `string[] widths = WidthStr.split(";");` then you have them all in an array... and you can do what ever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var numbers = WidthStr.Split(';').Select(double.Parse).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Or if you need only numbers different from the first one then (continuing previous code):

```
var otherNumbers = numbers.Skip(1).Except(numbers.Take(1));
```

Comment: You can do do `.Select(double.Parse)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var numbers = WidthStr.Split(';');
if(numbers.Length > 0)
{
    var differentNumbers = numbers.Skip(1).Where(x => x != numbers[0]);
    // ...
}
```